# Constructor shows an error?

Tags: c#, wpf

Following is the startup code for my application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using AFICController.ViewModel;


namespace AFICController
{
class App : Application
{
[STAThread()]
static void Main()
{
  Splasher.Splash = new SplashScreen();
  Splasher.ShowSplash();

  Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }

  Splasher.CloseSplash();
  new App();
 }
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public App()
{

  App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(@"\Resources\Dictionary\ATTColors.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });

  App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new U  Uri(@"\Resources\Dictionary\AppButton.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });

  Console.WriteLine("EULA Opened");
  StartupUri = new System.Uri("EULA.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

  //StartupUri = new System.Uri("View/WizardDialog.xaml", UriKind.Relative);


  Run();
}
```

I have above code to run my application .At first i have splash screen which appears very fine then i have a WPF window which is basically a EULA Agreement  but it compiler throws an exception "`The invocation of the constructor on type  that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.`" 
This exception comes out at Run() method in the above code.
Following is the WPF code for EULA:

```
<Window 
x:Class="AFICController.EULA" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:AFICController.Resources"
Title="{x:Static res:Strings.WizardWelcomeWindow_Title}"
Width="800"
Height="600"  
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
Icon="/AFICController;Component/Resources/Images/att_icon.ico"
ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

following is the EULA.xaml.cs code :

```
namespace AFICController
{
/// <summary>
 /// Interaction logic for EULA.xaml
 /// </summary>
 public partial class EULA : Window
 {
  public EULA()
  {
   InitializeComponent();

  //Closing += new CancelEventHandler(EULA_Closing);

  TextRange range;

  var fileName = "AFICController.Resources.EULA.EULA-Formatted activeARC.rtf";

  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

  var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);

  if (stream == null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("File Found");
  }

  range = new TextRange(EULAParagraph.ContentStart, EULAParagraph.ContentEnd);

  range.Load(stream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);

  }

 private void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog();

   wizardDialog.Show();

   this.Close();
 }

  private void DeclineButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   Application.Current.Shutdown();
 }
```

Any help would be highly appreciable as i have tried my all techniques and searched thoroughly??

Comment: why not thread.Sleep(5000)? it's not like you are doing anything else in the meantime..

Comment: Could you include the AFICController.EULA.xaml.cs file?

Comment: What I meant is that it would help if we could have a look at it - So could you edit your post and include the code? :)

Comment: I just added that piece of code .I think the issue is at where the stream is creating it always provides null value but i dont know how to sort out the actual problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that you only execute your code if stream is not null

```
  public EULA()
  {
   InitializeComponent();

  //Closing += new CancelEventHandler(EULA_Closing);

  TextRange range;

  var fileName = "AFICController.Resources.EULA.EULA-Formatted activeARC.rtf";

  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

  var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);

  if (stream == null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("File Found");

  range = new TextRange(EULAParagraph.ContentStart, EULAParagraph.ContentEnd);

  range.Load(stream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
  }

  }
```

If what you said is true i.e. the `stream` is always null maybe it's because the file is not a resource. In your project go to EULA-Formatted activeARC.rtf -> right click -> properties -> Build Action -> select 'Embeded Resource'.

Are you sure the fileName is correct? Looks a little bit like it could be a path (with / and not dots)?

Comment: Yes it is working now ..your guide me accurately Adam Blinski i changed the Build Action-> Embedded Resource and now it is working fine great suggestion :)